# Login Using Retrofit not working

Tags: android, rest, retrofit

I m creating user login with retrofit but i can't get username and password from the server()mysql ..I don't know what i m doing wrong.
Interface

```
public interface LoginApi {
            @FormUrlEncoded
            @POST("/zaala/retrofitlogin.php")
            public void getlogin(
            @Field("username") String username,
            @Field("password")String password,
            Callback response
            );
```

MainActivity

```
 private static final String ROOT_LOGIN = "http://xxxxx.com";
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

                editTextUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUsername);
                editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);

                buttonlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonlogin);
                buttonlogin.setOnClickListener(this);

                restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(ROOT_LOGIN).build();
                restAdapter.setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL);
                loginApi = restAdapter.create(LoginApi.class);
            }
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
           loginApi.getlogin(editTextUsername.getText().toString(), editTextPassword.getText().toString(), new Callback<String>() {
               @Override
               public void success(String s, Response response) {
                   Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Logged in",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
               @Override
               public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                   Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Logged Failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
           });
            }
```

Help--- i m using php code

Comment: Have you tried to turn on Retrofit logging to see what the raw HTTP request-response sequence looks like?

Comment: Can you post your login php code?

Comment: Can you show us what is a reason of RetrofitError  error?

Comment: Yes , inside the logs this what i can see  let me push on github ---> HTTP POST http://marbletileindustries.com/zaala/retrofitlogin.php
01-11 19:53:17.309 7879-8118/com.kevinjanvier.retrofitnetworkcallD/Retrofit: username=kevina&password=1111
"Fail"

Comment: Check the codes here : https://github.com/kevinjam/loginRetrofit.git
Help me Guys ..no sure why getting this @rendell

Comment: In your php file where you're checking the num rows, why is the if and else both printing "Fail"?

Comment: Not sure ..what y i need help @rendell

Comment: You said that you're getting a "Fail" as response. Maybe it's because in you php, in the if num_rows statement, both your if and else are displaying "Fail". Try changing the one in the else to "Success" and see if it works.

Comment: All that is done but no solution ...can u try to clone the code on github?